# Vectores C++ contador

Tags: c++

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que dos jugadores ingresan 5 cartas(MAX), ahi tengo que averiguar cual es la carta mas repetida y cuantas repeticiones tiene, he probado con esta funcion pero no termina de salir, a ver si me podeis echar un cable, la idea es pasar por referencia las repeticiones y devolver la carta que mas se repite.
La funcion es esta, si necesitais mas datos cuelgo todo el codigo, gracias!

```
int cartaRep(int cartas[], int MAX, int *repeticiones, int orden[]) {

int cartaRepe = 0;
int ordenVectores[12] = {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};

for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
        if (cartas[i] == orden[j])
        {
            ordenVectores[j]++;
        }
    }
}

for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
{
    if (ordenVectores[i] > cartaRepe)
    {
        *repeticiones = ordenVectores[i];
        cartaRepe = orden[i];
    }
}
return cartaRepe;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que veo tus cartas son un simple entero, puedes contar repeticiones usando un contenedor asociativo como `std::map` en que la clave sea la carta y el valor sea las repeticiones:

```
int cartas[] { 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8 };
using cartas_repetidas = std::map<int, int>;

cartas_repetidas repeticiones;

for (const auto &carta : cartas)
{
    auto [iterador, insertado] = repeticiones.emplace(carta, 0);
    ++iterador->second;
}

for (const auto &repeticion : repeticiones)
    std::cout << "Carta " << repeticion.first << ": " << repeticion.second << '\n';
```

El código anterior genera la siguiente salida:

> ```
> Carta 1: 2
> Carta 2: 2
> Carta 3: 3
> Carta 4: 1
> Carta 5: 1
> Carta 6: 1
> Carta 7: 2
> Carta 8: 1
> ```

Puedes verlo funcionando en [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/CrUvdq6aeHicWaMt).